How can I add purecounter.js to my WordPress site?
<div class="counter-number">
  <span data-purecounter-start="0"
        data-purecounter-end="6"
        data-purecounter-duration="1"
        class="purecounter"></span>
</div>

new PureCounter();

wp_register_script(
  'purecounter',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter_vanilla.js',
  array('jquery'),
  '1.5.0',
  true
);
wp_enqueue_script('purecounter');


Uncaught ReferenceError: PureCounter is not defined


The counter number not showing. Getting this error.

If you pass a boolean as the last parameter to wp_enqueue_script, it is interpreted as whether or not to place the <script> tag in the footer. You are passing true, so it is in the footer. This means your JavaScript runs new PureCounter(); before the <script> tag is discovered and loaded. You have a couple of options. 1) Change it to false so that it loads in the header. You might run into race conditions still however. 2) Load your JS with wp_add_inline_script. 3) Wrap your JS with a ready listener. My vote is for #3.
